# Why when installing any package through pip3, the configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError error occurs?

Tags: python, pip

When I install any package through pip3 for python 3.7.4 an error occurs in the form:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 393, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 57, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 913, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 445, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 320, in move_wheel_files
    prefix=prefix,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 166, in distutils_scheme
    d.parse_config_files()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 413, in parse_config_files
    val = parser.get(section,opt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 799, in get
    d)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 394, in before_get
    self._interpolate_some(parser, option, L, value, section, defaults, 1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 444, in _interpolate_some
    "found: %r" % (rest,))
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I didn’t have this before. This problem has appeared recently. The problem occurs on OS X Mojave version 10.14.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your current working directory for a `setup.cfg` file with unsupported syntax in it.

This is open issue [#5182 CLI parses unrelated config files and then crashes](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5182), created by me in April 2018.

As a workaround until the issue is fixed, you can `cd` into a different directory and try installing again.

Comment: Thank you for helped me! Yes, it was problem in my setup.cfg file.

Comment: Commenting a year later to say thanks. Same issue for me. Renamed my config file. All is well now